# Infinte Loop - Adding and Removing Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have syntaxed checked this several times, but cannot figure out why the functions are being recursively called:

```
function updateNewClasses() {
  function addNewClass() {
    updateNewClasses();
  }
  window.addEventListener( "hashchange", addNewClass );
  // Conditionals being skipped; no loops
  window.removeEventListener( "hashchange", addNewClass );
  location.href = '#';
  window.addEventListener( "hashchange", addNewClass );
}
```

The program keeps calling the hash change function which recursively calls `updateNewClass` leading to an endless loop.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `addEventListener` is in `updateNewClasses` which is called from `addNewClass` which is triggered from your `addEventListener` you keep adding the event listener each time it is triggered.

Additionally, your `updateNewClasses` is creating a "new" `addNewClass` that is *not removed* on any subsequent call to `updateNewClasses`. You will want to store the function you want to add/remove *outside* the scope of your callback so it can be removed.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
var addNewClass = function() {
  updateNewClasses();
}

var updateNewClasses = function() {
  // Remove the old listener, change the hash, and add the listener again
  window.removeEventListener("hashchange", addNewClass);
  location.href = '#';
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", addNewClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the *syntax* won't find the error because your code is *syntactically* correct.

Your "updateNewClasses" function does the following:

1. Add an event listener for "hashchange"
2. Remove that event listener
3. Trigger a hash change
4. Add the event listener again.

Once a "hashchange" event happens from *outside* the function, you'll start getting the bad behavior. The call to `removeEventListener` will only remove the handler added at the beginning of that call to "updateNewClasses"; the event listeners added at the end of any previous calls will remain in effect, because each call to "updateNewClasses" results in a completely new instance of the "addNewClass" function.

Comment: So, how do I fix this problem? I'm trying to get the page to scroll to the right position, but I need to track hash changes

Comment: @Isaiah see the other answer - if you ensure that the "addNewClass" function is unique, then calls to `removeEventListener()` will remove *all* listener assignments involving that function.